# How can I removeAttribute on an array of elements?

Tags: javascript

I want when i click a link, all the classes "selected" will be removed only the clicked link will be attributed the class selected

```
window.onload = function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('subMenu').getElementsByTagName('a');

    for(var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
          link[i].onclick = function() {
              link.removeAttribute('class');
              this.setAttribute('class', 'selected');
          }
    }
}
```

Firebug:

```
TypeError: link.removeAttribute is not a function
link.removeAttribute('class');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`link` is the collection you got from `.getElementsByTagName('a')`, and doesn't have a `removeAttribute` method. To refer to the specific item in the loop, you should use:

```
this.removeAttribute("class");
```

Since you already understand the concept of looping through the collection and modifying each item in the collection, and are using `this` for `setAttribute()`, you should continue using `this` to refer to the current item in the collection that you're modifying.

The value of `this` in an event handler refers to the element that the event is bound to, which is what you seem to want to modify (and are already modifying).

Also, I'm not exactly sure of the point of your code, since you remove the `class` attribute then immediately re-set it. If you really need to set the **attribute**, there's no reason to remove it in the first place. If you just want to change/set the `class`, use:

```
this.className = "selected";
```

Per your edit, you might want to use:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('subMenu').getElementsByTagName('a');

    for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
        link[i].onclick = linkClickHandler;
    }
};

function linkClickHandler() {
    var links = document.getElementById("subMenu").getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i] !== this) {
            links[i].className = "";
        } else {
            links[i].className = "selected";
        }
    }
}
```

This binds the `click` handler for all the found elements. In the handler, it loops through all the original elements - it sets the `class` as `"selected"` for the clicked element, and sets the `class` for all others as `""`.

Comment: i want when i click a link, all the classes will be removed only the clicked link will be attributed the class selected

Comment: @user2347768 I updated my answer with the code I'd use. Hopefully that helps :)